# Manjaro installer cannot boot into live usb

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation, live-usb, manjaro

I tried to install Manjaro 18.0.3 64 Bit, but after I selected boot in the welcome screen it did not work.

The following error showed up on screen:

```
ERROR: '/dev/disk/by-label/M1803' device did not show up after 30 seconds..
Falling back to interactive prompt
You can try to fix the problem manually, log out when you are finished
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

I already navigated into the /dev/disk/by-label directory, but the only device that could be my USB drive was named EFI, but renaming that and exiting didn't solve the problem.

At first I used Rufus to create the USB installer and a second attempt with Etcher failed as well, leading to the same error (and also no additional device listed in the mentioned directory).

Is there any solution to this problem?